# Reloading nginx & php5-fpm does not update changes to php.ini

Tags: nginx, php

I've made changes to `max_upload_size` in `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini` and restarted both nginx and php5-fpm services. `phpinfo()` states that `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini` is being loaded but after reloading/restartinb both services, `max_upload_size` remains unchanged.

**Question:** A server reboot solved the problem. Why is a reboot required? Did I miss out anything when restarting the services?

Comment: Make certain that max_upload_size was not set in the pool configuration for that host. If it is, then it does not matter what php.ini has because the pool configuration will always overwrite it in the end.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The issue is probably that you never actually restarted php-fpm. I had issues with this as well, apparently theres a bunch of different ways to restart php-fpm, and some of them dont work for certain environments.

https://serverfault.com/questions/189940/how-do-you-restart-php-fpm/506951

Try those and see if they reload it.

Answer (score 3):

CentOS 7, PHP 5.6, nginx 1.12 use

```
systemctl reload php-fpm
```

Comment: Very simple and straight to the point, saved me some head scratching since ole apache user.

Answer (score 3):

`nginx` is in use. whoever in rush editing `php.ini` like me this might be the correct paths to edit

```
/etc/php/7.4/fpm/php.ini
/etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
```

then to take effect

```
service php7.4-fpm restart
service nginx restart
```

also this one could help to see what process is running and where php.ini is

```
ps aux | grep php
php -i | grep php.ini
```

Answer (score 2):

I know there is already an answer to this but I also have had a similar problem to this one and [Galen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19453759/2768038)'s answer did not help with me.

---

My answer is to instead of editing `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini`, edit your `/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf` file and add to the end something like this:

```
php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 10M
```

Where `memory_limit` is the value you are wanting to edit on your `php.ini` and `10M`... I think you get the picture!

Comment: This does not answer the question... at all.

Answer (score 2):

If doing:
`sudo service php-fpm reload`

You get errors like:
`php-fpm: unrecognized service`

(Although you see it like this when doing `ps aux | grep php`)

Use command:
`sudo service --status-all | grep -i fpm`
to see the real names of services.

Then do:
`sudo service php7.3-fpm reload`
to reread php.ini