# DVWA setup - PHP function allow_url_include: Disabled

Tags: php, nginx, google-cloud-platform

I am setting up a DVWA on a Linux VM in Google Cloud.

When I click Create/Reset Database, one line that appears to have issues is `PHP function allow_url_include: Disabled`.

I've tried enabling it in the `php.ini` file inside the cloned `dvwa` repo, as well as `/etc/php/7.3/fpm/` and `/etc/php/7.3/cli/` directories but alas, even after running `sudo service nginx restart` and hitting the Create/Reset Database button doesn't resolve the issue.
I've also tried both, `On` and `"1"` as values for `allow_url_include` but none of them seemed to make any difference.

Is there another hidden php.ini file I need to edit or what am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: To setting configuration try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30221362/4356470) and [this](https://serverfault.com/a/189961) links

Comment: You can check currently used php.ini by the function phpinfo(), with this you can check the "allow_url_include" option as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found two ways to solve it.

1. Restarting the VM itself.
2. Running `sudo /etc/init.d/php7.3-fpm restart`

Thanks, @behroozrazzaghi, for the links.